# python ImportError: No module named Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter, redhat

Every time I tried to run `import matplotlib`,
I have error `ImportError: No module named Tkinter`.

The output result is as listed below:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  2 2016, 04:20:16) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
_backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
mod = mod._resolve()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
return _import_module(self.mod)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
```

I tried to install the `tk.x86_64` and `tk-devel.x86_64` packages, and tried to reinstall the python package but the error still appeared.
Also I tried to `import Tkinter` but I got the following error.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  2 2016, 04:20:16) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
```

Does anyone have a workaround for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to install tkinter package for python2.7.5 from the following link:
[tkinter package](ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/Packages/tkinter-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64.rpm)
Also I found there is dependency library libTix.so()(64bit) for tkinter package and i got it from the following link: [libTix.so()(64bit) package](ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/Packages/tix-8.4.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm)
after that i installed both then I could `import Tkinter` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` with no errors.

Comment: Glad you managed to install the packages you needed and fixed your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using python2.7.12 on ubuntu16.04.
I installed it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents. Open a terminal and type the following.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
>>>
```

If you do not get an error like below then your Tkinter is fine and the problem is with matplotlib. Then try removing and reinstalling matplotlib.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

Comment: I forgot to add i tried to `import Tkinter` and i have got mentioned error as following
`python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  2 2016, 04:20:16) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Tkinter`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error **"ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'"** for python3.5 in-spite of installing python3-tk and tkinter-dev.

It showed the error in following file:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 35, in 
>       import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

It got resolved for me by simply running the python from /usr/bin like ***/usr/bin/python3.5*** from terminal!

**In short, please ensure the python version being run from terminal has the tkinter installed and configured** :)

My PC configuration: Ubuntu16.04 with default python2.7 and python3.5

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue on a RHEL 7 machine. There was no `python-tk` package that could be installed. I found the solution [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7512/#issuecomment-262902507) which solved the issue for me:

```
sudo yum install tkinter
```

This should work for RHEL machines using Python 2.