# Tkinter/tkinter import problem Python2.7 and Python3.7, RHEl7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I am facing issues importing Tkinter in Python 2.7 and tkinter in Python 3.7 on RHEL7.

### Python 2.7:

Python 2.7.5 (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import Tkinter
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ImportError: No module named Tkinter

### Python 3.7:

Python 3.7.11 (default, Apr 18 2022, 13:29:46)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tkinter
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 36, in 
> > > import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tried installing respective modules as well. But it doesnt work

### Python 2.7:

pip install Tkinter
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Tkinter

### Python 3.7:

pip3 install tkinter
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter

I am running out of ideas.
If you have any suggestions, please comment

Regards!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435315/python-importerror-no-module-named-tkinter#:~:text=Add%20a%20comment-,2,Tkinter%20and%20import%20matplotlib.pyplot%20as%20plt%20with%20no%20errors.,-Share

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693107/no-module-named-tkinter-configured#:~:text=When%20building%20python,install%20tk%2Ddevel

Comment: Check the RHEL7 available packages list. Good chance that tkinter is a *separate package*. BTW, it's Python 3.7.11, not 3.11.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.